# node 10.26, zombiejs 2.0.0-alpha31, mocha 1.17.1 Error: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

New here so pardon if this "easy".

Here is my error, seems to be pretty generic. I've tried stepping through it but can't figure it out. I initially thought it was because there was a connection already opened with the same port but I can't see an active node process via ps (I check before running the test) so I'm thinking it has to be in the test somewhere. Other test connect to couchdb without errors so I've eliminated that being a possibility.

```
 Users
Signup Form
  connect ECONNREFUSED Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
  1) "before all" hook
```

This is the main portion of the test:

```
var assert      = require('assert'),
Browser     = require('zombie'),
fixtures    = require('./fixtures'),
couchdb     = require('../lib/couchdb'),
dbName      = 'users',
db          = couchdb.use(dbName),
app         = require('../app');

describe('Users', function () {

before(function (done) {
    app.start(3000, done);
});

after(function (done) {
    app.server.close(done);
});

describe('Signup Form', function () {

    before(function (done) {
        db.get(fixtures.user.email, function (err, doc) {
            if (err && err.status_code === 404) return done();
            if (err) throw err;
            db.destroy(doc._id, doc._rev, done);
        });
    });

    it("should load the signup form", function (done) {
        Browser.visit("http://localhost:3000/users/new", function (err, browser) {
            if (err) throw err;
    .....
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I also tried changing the port number several times - nothing.

Comment: My guess would be this line of code is causing the problem: `db.get(fixtures.user.email, function (err, doc) {` Are you sure you have a connection to the DB?

Comment: @Kiran Thanks. Yes, I use the same code in other test before this one but in this case it doesn't even get to the db.get - I have a break point there. It is on the first before hook.